# can i use multiple socket connection in same device with backend?

Tags: android, sockets, socket.io, socket.io-client

can i use multiple socket connection ?
is it normal ?

frontend : Android Java
backend : Nodejs

issue : socket is disconnect after sometimes. i tried many ways to connect stable .
case : when user open app so they connect "globalRoom". [ for transfer call request data , call incme , call decline etc... ] and when user recives call so they connect in "videocallRoom"

here is two room means two socket connection with backed.
we have many users so milions of room connected with socket.

i have doubt in multiple rooom connection.
So question is : is it good to connect multiple socket with same device to backend or use any single room , connection for this ??

i try every possible cases to solve it
but there is no solution happed as i want.

Comment: "Is it normal?" Yes, if that's what you need.